# Get unique dictionaries from array of dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that looks like this:

```
dateArray = [
      {year:'2018', month: "01"},
      {year:'2018', month: "01"},
      {year:'2017', month: "02"},
      {year:'2017', month: "02"}
    ];
```

I'd like to get the unique values from that array and have tried doing it like this:

```
  let unique = [...new Set(this.state.dateArray.map(item => item.Group))];
  console.log('UNIQUE: ',unique);
```

This solution does not work. How can I get the unique dictionaries in an array of dictionaries and put them in a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a cleaner way, but this deduplicates your array:

```js
const dateArray = [
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"}
];

const uniqueDates = [];
for (let date of dateArray){ // Use "of" to loop through an array
  let unique = true; // Set a flag to handle possible unwanted items 
  for (let uniqueDate of uniqueDates){
    if (uniqueDate.year == date.year && uniqueDate.month == date.month){
      unique = false; // Both properties match, so throw up the flag
    }
  }
  if(unique){ // Only add the item if the flag didn't go up
    uniqueDates.push(date);
  }
}
console.log(uniqueDates);
```

---

Or the same thing, but using [.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (which takes a callback function as an argument, which can be an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).)

```
const uniqueDates = [];
dateArray.forEach(date => { // the argument passed to the callback stores the current item
  let unique = true;
  uniqueDates.forEach(uniqueDate => {
    if (uniqueDate.year == date.year && uniqueDate.month == date.month){
      unique = false;    
    }
  });
  if(unique){
    uniqueDates.push(date);
  }
});
console.log(uniqueDates);
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want a new array with duplicates removed? You can `.filter()` the array down to objects where using `.findIndex` yields the same index as the current index:

```js
dateArray = [
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"}
];
    
var unique = dateArray.filter((o, i) =>
  i === dateArray.findIndex(oo => o.year === oo.year && o.month === oo.month)
);

console.log(unique);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is the appropriate data type to deal with uniqueness.  Unfortunately, in JS, these only deal with primitive and reference equality.  By transforming our data to and from primitive strings, however, we can use one to deal with the question of uniqueness directly.

This is one version that does so:

```js
const uniqDates = ds => [...new Set(ds.map(({year, month}) => `${year}-${month}`))]
  .map(s => s.split('-'))
  .map(([year, month]) => ({year, month}))

const dateArray = [
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"}
]

console.log(uniqDates(dateArray))
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick-n-dirty in O(n) time:

```js
const dateArray = [
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2018', month: "01"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"},
  {year:'2017', month: "02"},
];
console.log(Array.from(new Set(dateArray.map(d => JSON.stringify([d.year, d.month])))).map(
    s => {
        const d = JSON.parse(s);
        return {year: d[0], month: d[1]};
    }
))
```

I don't know of a general way to easily treat objects as comparable values other than stringifying them. Also, `JSON.stringify(d)` isn't suitable, since the order of serialization of the object's fields is indeterminate, hence the explicit packing and unpacking of fields. This is a shame, since it could have been much simpler:

```
# WRONG, DO NOT USE!
Array.from(new Set(dateArray.map(JSON.stringify))).map(JSON.parse)
```